# How to parse kernel coredump for dmesg logs?

Tags: linux-kernel, embedded-linux, coredump, dmesg

I want to read `dmesg` logs that are present in the kernel core file. The usual way is to make use of a utility like `crash` to open the core file with a corresponding `vmlinux`.

If I am not wrong, reading the `dmesg` logs from a core file has no symbol dependency and hence no `vmlinux` dependency.

Secondly, the running system may not have any utilities available to open core files. So I want to implement my own script/utility that can open the core file as a normal file and parse it to dump the dmesg logs.

Is it possible? If yes, what's the format of the core file, so that I can locate where the `dmesg` starts and end?

Comment: Maybe look at the source code of let's say `crash` (if any) and take a look at the implementation. If _there are_ kernel ring buffer logs in the coredump file then there must be a way to examine it, you'll have to read the specification ig. _what's the format of the core file_ ~ it must be documented somewhere, look it up.

Comment: @Roi : I couldn't locate the documentation anywhere, or maybe my search keywords were not to the point. Can someone please help locate it, if its really out there.

Answer (score 1):

The `crash` tool has in his interactive prompt the command `log` to display the kernel message buffer ([Analyzing a core dump](https://access.redhat.com/documentation/en-us/red_hat_enterprise_linux/8/html/managing_monitoring_and_updating_the_kernel/analyzing-a-core-dump_managing-monitoring-and-updating-the-kernel)). You'll find the source under [`crash-utility/crash`](https://github.com/crash-utility/crash) and may proceed further with searching for [`log_buf`](https://github.com/crash-utility/crash/search?q=log_buf).

> *What's the format of the core file, so that I can locate where the dmesg starts and end?*

It seems that "[*the core dump file format is using the ELF format but is not described in the ELF standard.*](https://stackoverflow.com/a/32341705/6771046)"

You may also find further information for "How to analyze Linux memory or core dumps" within the [Volatility Framework](https://github.com/volatilityfoundation/volatility) and which is written in Python. In example search for [`dmesg`](https://github.com/volatilityfoundation/volatility/search?q=dmesg).

Answer (score 0):

I don't believe the coredump file has kernel logs in in, if it had `strings` should've printed that out. What I think `crash` does is to print out the content in the kernel ring buffer to the user, if any. Usually when a fault occurs in the kernel, the kernel puts some useful information in the kernel ring buffer but it's not for user-space applications.

A coredump is simply just an `ELF` file with some additional data in it, if you want to parse the `ELF` format you'll have to look at the specs or maybe use a tool/library.